# Reference SharePoint dll from within a Silverlight Application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint

I need to build an external upload utility to send files up to SharePoint 2010. However, I can't reference SharePoint to call all of the code needed to work with a document library.

Is there any way to make this happen inside Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather not possible. Silverlight executes under a sandboxed environment with no direct access to server-side APIs.

Instead, create a WCF service at the server side, reference the Sharepoint DLL from within the service and call the service from Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

All answers are true and valid, however there IS a Client Object Model for SharePoint that you can use with Silverlight aswell. [Here](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-silverlight-client.html) is a great tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight runs on the client, not on the server, so you can't reference the SharePoint dlls. You would need to build a server-side service that uses the sharepoint dlls and then call that service from Silverlight.

There are built-in sharepoint developer entry points which I reference in [my blog post here](http://bryantlikes.com/GettingStartedWithSilverlightAndSharePoint2010.aspx). You could probably use these instead of using the sharepoint dll.